# PHP how do I turn on the in browser error logging

Tags: php, linux, error-handling

For example if my PHP script throws an error I want it to print to the browser. I am on a linux box  Debian 5.0

Comment: Ok maybe not a good question but a legitimate one. At least say why the down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this that the top of your php file:

```
//*DEBUG ERROR REPORTING
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//END DEBUG ERROR REPORTING*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the ini variable [`display_error`](http://php.net/display_errors) to 1, to display errors to the browsers.